# How to recover EtherLi Multi-Sig Wallet without SMS?

Tags: multisignature, recovery, ether-li

For any reason is phone number in my EtherLi Multi-sig wallet settings wrong.

I don't receive the 2nd verification code by SMS due to the wrong digit in my phone number. Please let me know how to update my profile in Ether.Li Multi-sig wallet or how to transfer my ETH.

Comment: Do you have any recovery information, i.e. printed out sheet?

Comment: Yes, I have all information printed

Comment: So if the SMS verification does not work, you should be able to recover using this sheet.

Comment: I have User Key, Backup key, Co-signer key, wallet address, backup private key and encrypted private key

Comment: If no SMS what is the 2nd factor authentication code to confirm the request.

Comment: I followed the recommendations according to Masosn's comment and in Mist it says that he transaction requires 1/2 Signature. When and how do I add it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use your recovery sheet which contains 2 of the 3 required private keys.

Place both private keys into a text file on your computer, open Geth or Parity and import it (or put it directly into the keystore of each client).

[image: backup sheet]

Start your favorite client and make sure both wallets are imported, sometimes you have to unlock and re-encrypt them.

And finally, add the public ether-li address to your multi-sig wallets. Now you can access it from your Mist or Parity wallet like a normal multi-sig wallet.

Comment: any chance you can expand on "Now you can access it from your Mist or Parity wallet like a normal multi-sig wallet."?

Comment: Haven't used Mist in a while, just add it as multi-sig wallet and .. use it ... where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I've just done the recovery without SMS, using Parity. These aren't necessarily the best steps, just what I ended up doing through trial and error.

1. Try to transfer using ether.li, from my ether.li wallet to account 0x1. Because I didn't receive any SMS, nothing was actually transferred, but the request was a tx on the blockchain.
2. Install parity https://parity.io/parity.html . All of the following steps are within parity.
3. Import a wallet using the Ether.li backup private key. Let's call this account 0x2
4. Fund 0x2 with a small amount (I used 0.01) from another account.
5. In http://127.0.0.1:8180/#/accounts, "Watch a wallet" and enter the address of **your** ether.li wallet. NB That's the one which is a contract holding your Ether, **not the ether.li contract**
6. Having imported your ether.li wallet, click on it and you should see Pending Confirmations with a single entry, this being the attempted ether.li transaction from step 1.
7. Click on "CONFIRM AS...", and choose the ether.li backup account 0x2 you created in step 3 and funded in step 4. You will need to wait until the funds from step 4 are received otherwise the confirmation will fail.

Answer (score -1):

You can recover with this guide if you have the recovery sheet:
https://masonborda.com/etherli-wallet-recoveries/

Alternatively, if only one digit is incorrect, you can email Etherli support.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Server no longer responding.