# ether.li OTP doesn't work

Tags: recovery, ether.li

When trying to transfer funds out of my ether.li account, I'm always getting an error message that I'm entering the wrong code. But it's definitely correct. Ether.li support doesn't reply.

Does anyone know of ANY solution that helps me transferring ether out of my wallet? Bit frustrated by know.. more than happy to compensate for efforts if successful.

Comment: I have the same problem, Did you find a solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/how-to-recover-etherli-multi-sig-wallet-without-sms

Comment: @ 5chdn: So I definitely need parity to solve this problem, correct? No possibility to get ether.li working for me?

Comment: I've posted the detailed parity recovery steps as an answer to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/how-to-recover-etherli-multi-sig-wallet-without-sms

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to open advanced (look down on the site), then confirm with your Password, so u do not need a signature from ether.
Should work - please give info.

Comment: I did as you said.. and then tried to initiate another transaction. Now the transaction appears in the transaction list as "request initiated by *user account no*" aaaand.. nothing happens. No ether are being sent. Am I missing sth?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the Private Key, you can move your money out without any issue.
If you don't have your key, check the ether.li account there must be some option to get the private keys.

The best wallet is Jaxx, I personally use this and it's same as electrum. The only thing you need to take care while using the desktop-based app is that you have to keep a backup your private key / or secret Wallet Generation Seed in a secure place in case of hard drive failure. Write it down and keep it offline. Don't store anywhere online.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Prateek! I do have the private key. However, when trying to send funds, I first have to enter my password (no issue here), then approve transaction with otp. But the otp is always rejected.. so how can I transfer funds with the private key only on ether.li?

Comment: Ether.li is no "account", it's a multi-signature wallet.

Comment: @5chdn Visit https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction and enter the private key to access your etherum and use it normally.