# Problem with import of ether.li wallet into Mist

Tags: mist, import, multisignature, ether.li

I am unable to follow the guide provided from the creator of ether.li: https://masonborda.com/etherli-wallet-recoveries/.

I managed to import both accounts via the console into Mist but I am unable to continue. Which account should be set as the owner and which adress should be imported?
I tried every possible combination and everytime a message pops up saying: The adress has no wallet-contract. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

I would be grateful for any help.

EDIT: Switching to Parity solved the Problem, there was a problem with the block syncing in Mist.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you import your Ether.li wallet into Parity?
Anyone can help?

Comment: I've just posted the parity steps as an answer to 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/how-to-recover-etherli-multi-sig-wallet-without-sms